# Jenkins doesn't recognize docker image on local machine

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

So, I am trying to use locally build docker image, that I pushed to local docker registry, in `Jenkinsfile` but when I run build in Jenkins it always fails with message: `Error: No such object: localhost:5000/rocky-8:latest`.

P.S. For the rest of the code below `echo 'Building Rpm...'` I expect to fail, I just need to pass this `docker` step.

This is my code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        PROJECT_DIR="fake-message-repo"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Check Docker') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checking if Docker exists...'
                sh 'docker --version'
            }
        }
        stage ('Test'){
            parallel {
                stage ('Test Rocky 8.1') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            image 'localhost:5000/rocky-8:latest'
                            args '-u jenkins:jenkins'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo 'Building Rpm...'
                        sh '''
                            cd ${WORKSPACE}/$PROJECT_DIR
                            rm -f .python-version &>/dev/null
                            source $HOME/pyenv.sh
                            PY310V=$(pyenv versions | grep ams-py310)
                            pyenv local 3.7.15 3.8.15 3.9.15 ${PY310V// /}
                            tox
                            coverage xml --omit=*usr* --omit=*.tox*
                        '''
                        cobertura coberturaReportFile: '**/coverage.xml'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo "deploying the aplication... wooooow!!!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In order to create registry, push and pull images from it I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49322766/how-to-look-for-a-docker-image-on-the-local-machine) answer.
I also tried adding `localhost:5000` in Jenkins configuration but it didn't work. [image]

and this is my local docker registry:
[image]

What am I missing here? Thx for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found why it didn't work for me. Before I used Jenkins documentation that explains how to create [Jenkins with Docker](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/) but since this is all new to me maybe I missinterpreted documentation and that is why it didn't work for me.

Now I used this command to build jenkins that contains docker: `docker run -u 0 --privileged --name jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts` which I found here:
[jenkins pipeline : docker not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264319/jenkins-pipeline-docker-not-found)

And finally in my `Jenkinsfile` I removed commands that execute shell commands inside step inside `stage ('Test')` to make sure that it doesn't interfere with building process and it worked:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment {
        PROJECT_DIR="fake-message-repo"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Check Docker') {
            steps {
                echo 'Checking if Docker exists...'
                sh 'docker --version'
            }
        }
        stage ('Test'){
            parallel {
                stage ('Test Rocky 8.1') {
                    agent {
                        docker {
                            image 'localhost:5000/rocky8:latest'
                            args '-u root:root'
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo 'Building Rpm...'
                        sh 'python --version'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo "deploying the aplication... wooooow!!!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```